# @Check instead of @Test

Tags: junit5

In JUnit there is the @Test annotation. According to James Bach and Michael Bolton that can be considered a misleading label in that context.

More appropriate would be **@Check**. Checking can be automated unlike testing.

See Bolton's blog where he explains what a test is and what an automated check is: http://www.developsense.com/blog/2009/08/testing-vs-checking/ (read the old version first is my recommendation).

So my question is if you want to change @Test into @Check in JUnit 5 in order to contribute to a more appropriate view on the subject amongst developers?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly your question is? As it stands it sounds like you're asking the JUnit team, which you should do [over at GitHub](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5).

Comment: Yes, I mean the JUnit team. I will post it in the GitHub as you say.
It was not really a question but a suggestion for JUnit 5.